# Should the tags 'qubit-state' and 'qubit' be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are quite few tags with the [qubit-state](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit-state) and [qubit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit). Are these fundamentally different? Should the tags 'qubit-state' and 'qubit' be merged?

If not, why are these things different? We should then update the tag usage to indicate this.

If yes, then we should probably pick one to keep (I think [qubit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit) is better) and let the other be a synonym.

Answer (score 5):

I think these tags should be kept. In my opinion a question talking about [qubit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit)s can talk about more things than just their state: how to get qubits? (on-topic? Not sure), properties of qubits required for them to work, how to store qubits (on-topic? Not sure) and of course also about their states.

Whereas [qubit-state](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit-state) is, in my opinion, only about questions regarding to the state of qubits.

You can probably be an expert knowing everything about the possible states of qubits and know nothing about how to get/produce them.

That is why I am thinking that we should keep both tags, maybe add to the excerpt of [qubit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit) that questions using this tag should have at least one other tag like [qubit-state](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit-state), [qubit-production](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qubit-production)...

A draft for the new excerpt is this:

> For questions related to quantum bits. Please add at least one more specific tag to specify the precise problem (e.g. [qubit-state] or [qubit-production]). Also try to indicate whether you're interested in theoretical or 'implementation' results.

Comment: Can you give a concrete suggestions for a new excerpt?

Comment: Oh and perhaps this is yet another case for the 'implied-tag' feature...

Comment: @Discretelizard maybe something like this: `For questions related to quantum bits. Please add at least one more specific tag: [qubit-state], [qubit-production]` (I can't think of other examples for sub-tags) || Yes, implied tags would be useful for this.

Comment: @Discretelizard feel free to edit my post. I think other people shall be able to edit my post, to add arguments, .... I will only complain/rollback if someone is changing the intent of my post.

Comment: @Discretelizard I suppose we should wait for some meta-consent (maybe wait 1/2 days) before starting to write this tag excerpt.

Comment: Sure, if that is what you want.

Comment: I like this idea. I think you should go ahead and write that excerpt. The reviewers will do their job in due time. Also, if you feel any of the existing questions need the tag [tag:qubit-production], feel free to suggest it.